# How to remove Storyboard after begin it in UWP?

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm working on the UI animations with my UWP project. When I combined the Storyboard with translate transform based on user's manipulation in a control, it's seem like the tranlastion didn't work anymore after the Storyboard had begun its animation.

After researching, I thought this is [the reason](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970493(v=vs.110).aspx) -
 that I can't change the value of a property after it has been animated, and I have to remove the Storyboard,... Unfortunately this article is support for WPF so I can't apply to my UWP project. So does anyone know any solutions for this situation ?

XAML:

```
   <Frame       x:Name="StoreFrame"
                Grid.Row="1"
                Grid.RowSpan="1"
                MaxWidth="400"
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                ManipulationDelta="StoreFrame_OnManipulationDelta"
                ManipulationMode="TranslateY">
                <Frame.RenderTransform>
                    <CompositeTransform x:Name="Transform" />
                </Frame.RenderTransform>
   </Frame>
```

Manipulation event handler:

```
    private void StoreFrame_OnManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       Transform.TranslateY += e.Delta.Translation.Y;
    }
```

My Storyboard animation:

```
    private void ShowStoreFrameAnimation()
    {
        VerticalAnimatiton(StoreFrame, StoreFrame.ActualHeight, 0);
    }

    public void VerticalAnimatiton(DependencyObject controlObject, 
                                   double fromValue, double toValue, double durationTime = 1000)
    {
        //The animation things
        var storyboard = new Storyboard();

        var duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(durationTime));
        var ease = new CubicEase { EasingMode = EasingMode.EaseOut };

        var animation = new DoubleAnimation
        {
            EasingFunction = ease,
            Duration = duration
        };
        storyboard.Children.Add(animation);
        animation.From = fromValue;
        animation.To = toValue;
        animation.EnableDependentAnimation = false;
        Storyboard.SetTarget(animation, controlObject);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, "(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateY)");        

        storyboard.Begin();
    }
```

Comment: You should use the _same_ `Storybard` to handle user manipulation - `Pause` it when user interaction begins (`ManipulationStarted`), call `Seek` during the interaction (`ManipulationDelta`), and finally `Resume` it once the interaction ends (`ManipulationCompleted`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to remove Storyboard after begin it in UWP?
>
> I can't change the value of a property after it has been animated, and I have to remove the Storyboard.

As you said that we can't change the value of a property after it has been animated. And there is no viable way to remove the storyboard. But you can add the new `storyboard` for same property that has been used. the following code is a workaround for your scenario.

Add the new storyboard to the StoreFrame_OnManipulationDelta event method.

```
private void StoreFrame_OnManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
 {
     Transform.TranslateY += e.Delta.Translation.Y;

     var duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000));
     var ease = new CubicEase { EasingMode = EasingMode.EaseOut };
     var animation = new DoubleAnimation
     {
         EasingFunction = ease,
         Duration = duration
     };
     var conStoryboard = new Storyboard();
     conStoryboard.Children.Add(animation);
     animation.From = Transform.TranslateY;
     animation.To = Transform.TranslateY += e.Delta.Translation.Y;
     animation.EnableDependentAnimation = false;
     Storyboard.SetTarget(animation, StoreFrame);
     Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, "(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateY)");
     conStoryboard.Begin();
 }
```

Animation effect

[image]

Comment: Creating a new `Storyboard` each time the delta is invoked is giong to be very costy.

Comment: I have tested the memory consumption, not very serious.